# Media (photo & media) browser in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

In iOS, I am using this library to present images and video.

https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser

I am beginner in ionic and I am finding something like that.

I saw like this. But it doesn't support video.How shall I do? Can I modify < img > to show video?

https://github.com/kevincobain2000/ionic-photo-browser

https://github.com/AlexDisler/ionic-zoom-view

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am the author of ionic-photo-browser.
It is a wrap around Framework 7's photo browser. I looked at their documentation and it appears videos are supported.

https://framework7.io/docs/photo-browser.html

```
  var photos = [
    {
        url: 'image1.jpg',
        caption: 'Caption 1'
    },
    // Video element with caption
    {
        html: '<video src="video1.mp4"></video>',
        caption: 'Video Caption'
    },
    // This one is embedded video without caption
    {
        html: '<iframe src="..."></iframe>',
    },
    // This one will be also video without caption
    '<video src="video2.mp4"></video>'
];
```